# Python, Tkinter: Can a list be modified within a button callback without using global variables or defining new classes?

Tags: python, arrays, tkinter, callback, global-variables

Ideally, I would like to use a built-in approach like `tk.StringVar` to modify a list (of strings) in a button command, but also need the modified list to live on so it can be modified in additional function calls.  The line `print(a)` in the code below prints a list-like object `('abc', 'gh', 'rstu')`, but the line `print(a[1])` fails to return `gh` and the line `a.append('xyz')` returns an error (included further below), suggesting that I can't directly hijack `tk.StringVar` to carry the list.  What is then my best option, if I should avoid the perils of making the list global and the overhead of defining a class?

```
import tkinter as tk

def append():
    a = a_var.get()
    print(a)
    print(a[1])
    a.append('xyz')
    a_var.set(a)

a_arr = ['abc','gh','rstu']
print(a_arr)

window = tk.Tk()
a_var = tk.StringVar()
a_var.set(a_arr)

tk.Button(window, text='Append', command=append).pack()

window.mainloop()
```

---

For completeness, the output and error returned by the above code is

```
['abc', 'gh', 'rstu']
('abc', 'gh', 'rstu')
'
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1884, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\...\TestAppend.py", line 7, in modify
    a.append('xyz')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: The error seems self-explanatory. You've defined `a` as a string inside the function (`a = a_var.get()`), and strings don't have an `append` method.

Comment: @Bryan  I agree.  It's self-explanatory.

Comment: If you want to modify the global `a`, don't define a local `a`. Use some other variable name.

Comment: Of course there's no change, you're still trying to call `append` on `a`, and `a` is a string.

Comment: @Bryan  Yes, I agree.  The point of including the code example is to give a MWE "that I can't directly hijack tk.StringVar to carry [an] array" -- perhaps an obvious point as well, but I thought the MWE might give a starting point that would make answering the question easier.

Comment: Why are you trying to store the array in a `StringVar`? Why not just directly modify `a_arr`?

Comment: @Bryan Because I want to append to the array when I press the button, but without using global variables (or writing additional classes) if possible.  Using `command=lambda: append(a_arr)`, I could pass `a_arr` to append, but I don't have a way to "return" back the modified `a_arr` after `append()` has completed.

Comment: You don't have to return anything from the callback. If you pass in an array and append to it, you will be appending to the array itself, not a copy.

Comment: Err... “return back the modified a_arr...” You don’t have to return it back. You can mutate the list a_arr, and the original reference will still be valid since you are only mutating the contents.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to append to `a_arr`, you can pass it into the callback using `lambda`. There's no need for the callback to return anything since you will be modifying the object rather than replacing it with a new object.

If you made the following modifications to your code, you'll see that each time you click the button, the array grows by one.

```
def append(a):
    a.append('xyz')
    print("a:", a)
...
tk.Button(window, text='Append', command=lambda: append(a_arr)).pack()
```

Of course, since `a_arr` is already a global variable, you can also just directly modify it

```
def append():
    a_arr.append('xyz')
...
tk.Button(window, text='Append', command=append).pack()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with list then do convert it to `StringVar`

```
import tkinter as tk

def append():
    print(a_arr)
    print(a_arr[1])
    a_arr.append('xyz')

a_arr = ['abc','gh','rstu']

window = tk.Tk()
tk.Button(window, text='Append', command=append).pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Button runs assigned function without arguments - but you could use `lambda` to change it and send array as argument. But button also doesn't know what to do with returned value so you can't send back new array in `return` - and here you have to use global variable. When you write all GUI as classes then you can use `self.` and then it is not so bad.

```
import tkinter as tk

class App():

    def __init__(self):

        self.a_arr = ['abc','gh','rstu']

        self.window = tk.Tk()
        tk.Button(self.window, text='Append', command=self.append).pack()

        self.window.mainloop()    

    def append(self):
        print(self.a_arr)
        print(self.a_arr[1])
        self.a_arr.append('xyz')

App()
```